# Consulta sql con Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, propel

Tengo el siguiente problema: Estoy generando una cosulta SQL en symfony , el problema es que no me traer los archivos nulos osea: Si el archivo es S me los va a mostrar y si es null me los va a mostrar junto con los archivos S.

```
$c->add(LoteCartasPeer::ID_ENTIDAD, $this->l_entidad['id']);
    $c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(LoteCartasPeer::NRO_LOTE);
    $c->addJoin(LoteCartasPeer::ID_SUCURSAL, SucursalPeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $c->add(LoteCartasPeer::GRABA_TARJETA, 'S', Criteria::EQUAL);
```

Como podria preguntar si es S o es NULL o bien si es S y es NULL

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar la clausula where en tu consulta

```
 ->andWhere('S.nombre_del_campo IS NOT NULL')
```

Te dejo un enlace para que veas otro ejemplo

[enlace](https://blog.liplex.de/is-not-null-with-symfony-query-builder/)